# Java read from file line by line not reading lines correctly

Tags: java

I've saved a good few tweets in a text file with the following format:

```
Country:Brazil_result.txt Date: \r\n09/19/14 TweetTextExtract: #Brazil on track to becoming the leader of #wind #energy production in Latin America http://t.co/MFJjNPxodf
Country:Brazil_result.txt Date: \r\n09/19/14 TweetTextExtract: @ConceptOfficial FOLLOW ME GUYS PLEASE I LOVE YOU SO MUCH BRAZIL LOVE YOUx16
Country:Brazil_result.txt Date: \r\n09/19/14 TweetTextExtract: @JamesFenn90 plenty teams travelled far more in Brazil from their bases to each game.I'm sure eng can manage a trip to Amsterdam etc etc
```

Now what I look to do is read in line by line from the text file and then split the line by `"TweetTextExtract: "` but for some reason I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1` error and I can't see why as every line has the `"TweetTextExtract: "` term. Here is the error in the console:

```
Country:Brazil_result.txt Date: \r\n09/19/14 @ConceptOfficial FOLLOW ME GUYS 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at WhatToThink.main(WhatToThink.java:28)
```

The line with this tweet has the `"TweetTextExtract: "` term and so does the line succeeding it. I'm not to sure why this is breaking. Here is the code:

```
String folderPath = "C:/Users/me/workspace/Sentiment Analysis/Good Data";

        File fin = new File(folderPath + "/Brazil_result" + ".txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] stringline = line.split("TweetTextExtract: ");
            System.out.println(stringline[0] + stringline[1]);
            //System.out.println(line);
        }

        br.close();
```

Comment: Well that line 'PLEASE I LOVE YOU SO MUCH BRAZIL LOVE YOUx16' does not contain the TweetExtract thingie

Comment: Its just the way the line copied. In the text file all of that is on one line

Comment: @Icewind If you see the text in edit mode its actually a word wrap and not a new line.

Comment: No, it is on a separate line. The printout before the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException contains the part immediately before.

Comment: Is `\r\n` as text or as special character `line feed` and `new line` ?

Comment: I would suggest the print line before the split. So you know which line is causing problem.

Comment: You should uncomment the "System.out.println(line);" but put it BEFORE the splitter. It looks like it is treating everything from Country to GUYS as one line and everything from PLEASE onwards as a separate line (which would explain why it has no 'TweetExtract'). Could be to do with those weird characters you have that are showing as squares.

Comment: @Matt clearly its breaking on the line  PLEASE I LOVE YOU SO MUCH because it doesn't have my split element but my question is why is it reading as 2 separate lines? In the text file this is all one line and when java reads it, its breaking the line apart for some reason? Why? Because its breaking before the special characters as well

Comment: I ran your code and I do not get an error. The only things I changed are: (1) adding exception handling required by the compiler; (2) the text file's charset is UTF-8 and `new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost surely a bad text encoding for your file. Save your file as UTF-8 (or UTF-16), then use

```
new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8") //or UTF-16
```

If the encoding you use in the above constructor does not match the one of the text file, you will get gibberish and then the `split` won't work even on the first line.

If you want to keep the original encoding for you text file, just find out what it is and use it instead.

Comment: Yip it turned out to be an encoding problem

Answer (score 1):

it actually doesn't give the exception for me when i run it.but how ever you can avoid this error by dynamically print element inside splited String.the following enhanced loop will gives you the same result ..

```
String[] stringline = line.split("TweetTextExtract: ");
for (String s : stringline) {
            System.out.print(s);
} 
System.out.println("");
```

and you can find your self how much element exist inside the stringline array by looking at the result.

Comment: *"that's why you got array out of bound exception in 3rd line"* All lines contain the delimiter string.

Comment: @user1803551 yes i saw it's not the problem after user edit question .then i edited my one 

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
if (line.contains("TweetTextExtract: ")){
     String[] stringline = line.split("TweetTextExtract: ");
     System.out.println(stringline[0] + stringline[1]);
}
else{
     System.out.println("Line doesn't't contain \"TweetTextExtract: \"");
}
```

Comment: I would also print out the line itself, that does not contain "TweetTextExtract" - that way you can see where it's going wrong

Comment: OP doesn't give further information how to manage lines that doesn't contain  "TweetTextExtract: ". And that's way I gave a hint how he could solve the OutOfBoundsException.

Comment: *"In 3rd line the split method returns an array with only one element.*" All lines contain the delimiter string.

Comment: 37 minutes ago they weren't.

Comment: So I am notifying you that now they are :)